# How to determine that no exceptions have been caught java

Tags: java, exception, xml-parsing, sax

I have a code for my xml file validation:

```
try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setValidating(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

            public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("Error: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("Fatal error: " + exception.getMessage());
            }

            public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println("Warning: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
        });

            Document doc = builder.parse(xml);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

I can't figure out how should I organize my exception handling, so I could print message `"File is valid!"` like this `System.out.println(xml + " is valid!");` or similarly.

Comment: Just place the message at the end of the `try` block. if an exception is thrown, no further instructions in `try` are executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. I simply had to add `throw exception;` lines to my `ErrorHandler` methods so I could track a validation process.

Answer (score 2):

If this line

```
Document doc = builder.parse(xml);
```

did not throw an exception, parsing worked. Do what you want after this line.

The bodies of the methods of the `ErrorHandler` should perhaps not only print output and continue. An error of fatal error should stop parsing.

Comment: It seems that it catches errors/warrnings/fatal errors during execution of parse() with errorhandler. so even if I add my lines `Document doc = builder.parse(xml);
   System.out.println(xml + " is valid");` just before catch clauses it prints it no matter the file is valid or not

Answer (score 1):

Just add that line right before you start the `catch` clauses. If it gets to there, it means that no exceptions have been raised.

Comment: well this solution is one of maaaaaaaany, so you could just use this.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the javadoc for [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method. it would return `null` if any exception occurred. Then you can check for `doc == null` next after the try/catch block or in the `finally` block.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it only throws and exception if its argument is invalid, but i need to track a validation process during the execution of the parse method.